# WCF - Return All rows by ID to XML

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, entity-framework

I'm new in WCF and I just want to return all objects/records that the Id matches the Id provided by the client. Up till now, I just did the WCF return the objects one by one. Follow My Code:

**The Operation and Data Contracts:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IVdnLoginService
{
    [OperationContract]
    VdnLoginDac GetVdnByLoginDac(string loginDac);
}


[DataContract]
public class VdnLoginDac
{
    [DataMember]
    public int VdnLoginDacId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long VdnId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string VdnName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LoginDacName { get; set; }
}
```

The Service translating the EF Model to my custom Model:

```
 public class VdnLoginService : IVdnLoginService
{
    public VdnLoginDac GetVdnByLoginDac(string loginDac)
    {
        Entities dbContext = new Entities();
        var VdnEntity = (from v 
                             in dbContext.LOGINVDNNAMES
                             where v.LOGIN == loginDac
                             select v).FirstOrDefault();
        if (VdnEntity != null)
        {
            return TranslateLoginVdnNamesEntityToVdnLogin(VdnEntity);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Vdn invalido");
        }
    }

    private VdnLoginDac TranslateLoginVdnNamesEntityToVdnLogin(LOGINVDNNAMES LoginVdnNamesEntity)
    {
        VdnLoginDac vdnLoginDac = new VdnLoginDac();
        vdnLoginDac.VdnLoginDacId = LoginVdnNamesEntity.VDNEMPLOYEEID;
        vdnLoginDac.EmployeeId = LoginVdnNamesEntity.EMPLOYEEID;
        vdnLoginDac.LoginDacName = LoginVdnNamesEntity.LOGIN;
        vdnLoginDac.VdnId = LoginVdnNamesEntity.VDNID;
        vdnLoginDac.VdnName = LoginVdnNamesEntity.VDNNAME;

        return vdnLoginDac;

    }

}
```

I know if I take the FirstOrDefault() off, I will be able to retrive all records, but I do not know how the WCF will read all the data.

Answers and any suggests will be very apreciated =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can do to enable the collection to be returned.

First, change the return type of the method from `VdnLoginDac` to `List<VdnLoginDac>` so you can return a list of the matching records.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IVdnLoginService
{

    [OperationContract]
    List<VdnLoginDac> GetVdnByLoginDac(string loginDac);
}
```

Second, replace `FirstOrDefault()` with `ToList()` in your implementation of the method, and do the mapping of the individual records to `VdnLoginDac` in the query, like this:

```
public List<VdnLoginDac> GetVdnByLoginDac(string loginDac)
{
    Entities dbContext = new Entities();
    var VdnEntity = (from v 
                         in dbContext.LOGINVDNNAMES
                         where v.LOGIN == loginDac
                         select new VdnLoginDac() {
                             VdnLoginDacId = v.VDNEMPLOYEEID,
                             EmployeeId = v.EMPLOYEEID,
                             LoginDacName = v.LOGIN,
                             VdnId = v.VDNID,
                             VdnName = v.VDNNAME
                         }).ToList();

    return VdnEntity;
}
```

Note that there's no checking for whether `VdnEntity` is null or has a count of 0.  The client should check that, rather than having the service throw an exception.  If that exception is not handled by the service, it will bring the service down and the client's communication channel will be in a faulted state.

Comment: Tim, now it's working!Also, your explanation about the exceptions was really nice! Thank you very much!